# Can Visual Studio indicate errors like Netbeans does?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, netbeans

I am a CS student and last year I have been working with Netbeans to study java. Now I am starting work in Visual Studio 2012 with C/C++. The thing is I got accustomed to a little feature Netbeans had that VS does't seem to match. For syntax errors, Netbeans used to show the error once using a squigly line under the wrong syntax AND on the left side (where the line numbering is) it shows a red symbol of sorts to mark the line where the error is. Furthermore, on mouse over, both of them showed the same error message.
VS only seems to have the squigly line, which is fine, but in some cases (like forgetting to close a paranthesis) the squigly line is very small and hard to notice, that's where the red symbol came in handy. You could just hover mouse over it and it would show the error in the line in question.

Comment: If you double click on the error message, it will take you to the line with the error.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but that is only after you compile/run. I wan't to know beforehand.